# Swift CoreData : Check Date is Available Control

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using CoreData. I'm adding date and some datas. I need a if statement. This is if statement will work like that :

"if this date is available in CoreData database, user won't add any data."

I used this:

```
if newuser.valueForKey(NSDate) as NSDate == NSDate()
```

This is absolutely wrong. I'm new and i don't create this if statement. how can i do this ?

Thanks already !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the dates you should be using `isEqualToDate`:

```
if newuser.valueForKey(NSDate).isEqualToDate(NSDate())
```

But, dates are very accurate, so the current date would need to match the saved date, and that's never going to happen - at least a part of a second will have passed before you make the comparison.

So, what you really need to do is to find out what day, month and year the date is an compare those.

In a number of ways it would be best to store these values explicitly in Core Data instead of using a date object, though both would work. In either case you need to get the date components from the date in order to find out the day, month and year and then you need to compare them (possibly creating a date with only day, month and year and no time so you can compare it to the stored date which should also have no time set).